# Twitter bootstrap tooltip does not show up on focus on inputs inside the modal dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, tooltip, popover

I have a modal with form. Inputs have a popovers, which shows up when input is focused and hides when blur.

When I open a modal, then click in first input - popover gets displayed properly. But after that it does not work.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-title="Foo">
<input type="text" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-title="Bar">
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$("input[data-toggle='tooltip']").on('focus', function() {
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});

$("input[data-toggle='tooltip']").on('blur', function() {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that the problem in displaying `tooltip` on `inputs` is occurring because the inputs are inside the `modal` .

The tooltips could be displayed even for the inputs inside the modal but as **the `z-index` of modal is greater than the toopltip** you would not be able to see them.

**I changed the z-index of the tooptip element and now it is working, so you can refer this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/WL2Qa/)** to see a live example**

HTML :

```
<input type="text" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-title="Foo">
  <br>  
<input type="text" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-title="Bar">

    <br><br>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <input type="text" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-title="Foo">
  <br>  
<input type="text" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-title="Bar">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

JS:

```
$("input[data-toggle='tooltip']").on('focus', function() {
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});

$("input[data-toggle='tooltip']").on('blur', function() {
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});
```

css:

```
.tooltip{
    z-index:100000000;
}
```